# Questions about Solr Sharding

Tags: solr, sharding

We have a product (let's call it 'prod1') that we want to "integrate" with another product (let's call it 'prod2'), when "integrate" means that the prod1 + prod2 will be the "prod3".
We also have some plans to add more "products" into prod3.

So far so good.

We use Solr to provide search for users in both products, and both index could be very, very big and receive a lot of calls/sec. If we leave everything in one server, the throughput will be a crap.

So, we're think about use sharding (I believe that's the correct terminology, sorry if I'm wrong), but, I have some questions about it:

1. Is it possible to split the index by "one-product-index-per-machine"  or something like that? If yes, how do you suggest me do that?
2. If (question 1 == true) then let's suppose that prod1 index will be machine1, and prod2 index machine2, can I made a search in both machine1 and 2 "merging" the results with scores, offsets, etc, in a "easy" and correct way?
3. I read something about replication factor, but I think I don't understand it right. What's exactly it purpose?
4. I'm not sure if I use the correct terminology here, so, maybe someone can clarify what exactly is a core, shard, etc. This type of "simple" doubt are generating a lot of misunderstandings in my team.

By now, that's questions. Maybe I'll edit it later and add more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your questions in order:

1. It's up to you to define how you want to distribute your documents. You select which server you want to index your document to, and if you decide to do that for one product index pr. server, that's your decision (choose which server to use for indexing based on the which product the document originates from).
2. Yes. the shards=-parameter of the query string sent to Solr indicate which servers should be searched and merged into one response. As long as you don't see going high into the offsets as a possible issue, this shouldn't be a problem (the issue with high offets being that Solr have to retrieve up to (offset) documents from each server, to be able to do scoring across all shards).

   shards=server1:8080/solr/corename,server2:8080/solr/corename
3. Replication factor is relevant for SolrCloud, which hides away some of the complexity of doing manual sharding (but also introduces some). With SolrCloud Solr will determine which nodes to use for storage by itself, and the replication factor tells Solr how many servers you want to store the document on. If your replication factor is three, at least three servers will have to fail before a document becomes unreachable. If you're doing manual sharding, you'll have to set up replication by yourself and know what servers are backup servers as you'd do with a regular Solr setup.
4. Shard = Server that keeps only a subset of all the documents in an index, core = One index on one server - a server may contain several cores, where each core is a separate set of configuration and schema (previously you could only have one core in each Solr instance - Solr had one index and nothing more). SolrCloud was released for the first time with Solr 4.0, and is starting to gain some traction.

The [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) is a good place to start digging for more information about these concepts.

Comment: thanks, it clarify my mind a lot about solr/solrcloud concepts.

Comment: one last question: let's suppose I have 4 servers with same data, in which one I actually do the search queries? Also, I have to check every time it's up before search? What you suggest?

Comment: If you have four servers with the same data, just pick one randomly - or better, use a load balancer. The load balancer will remove nodes that are down, and retry them at regular intervals to see if it's back. We use mod_jk in apache with tomcat and solr on the backend nodes for this.

Comment: So if it is sharded in two different locations, how do I tell the app to point to a certain instance on a certain machine in a different country. Based on the user's account.